# Thunderbird/gmail : How to filter emails to receive/read from certified contacts

Tags: email, filter, gmail, thunderbird

in Thunderbird or Gmail how to filter email to receive/read emails from certified contacts with signed certificates?

Can this be answered for Gmail?

Answer (score 0):

This is my filter in Thunderbird:

[image: This is the solution in Thunderbird]